# Texture displaying on both triangles forming a square instead of only on one

Tags: c, opengl

I have tried to put a texture on a square, made out of two triangles, but it isn't displaying on the square and it is on both triangles seperately. I followed many tutorials, but they don't go into much details on how to fix this. It seems, that I need to change my shader, but I don't know how to go about this. Please tell me what to change!

This is a picture of the window:

[image]

This is my code:

```
#define GLEW_STATIC
#define STB_IMAGE_IMPLEMENTATION
#include<stdio.h>
#include<GL/glew.h>
#include<GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include<stdbool.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stb/stb_image.h>

GLint uniColor;
void key_callback();

int main(){ 
   if(!glfwInit()){
      printf("Failed to initialize glfw!\n");
      return 1;
   }else{
      printf("Successfully initialized glfw!\n");
   }
   glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
   glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
   glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);
   glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE); 
   GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(1054, 1057, "Title", NULL, NULL);
   glfwSetKeyCallback(window, key_callback);
   if(!window){
      printf("Window creation failed!\n");
      return 1;
   }else{
      printf("Window created successfully!\n");
   }
   glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
   glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
   if(glewInit() != GLEW_OK){
      printf("Failed to initialize glew!\n");
      return 1;
   }else{
      printf("Successfully initialized glew!\n");
   } 
   glfwSwapInterval(1);
   float Vertices[] = {
     -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
     -0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
      0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
      0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f
   };

   GLuint indices[] = {
      0, 2, 1,
      0, 3, 2
   };

   float VerticesSquare[] = {
      -0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f,
       0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f,
       0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,
      -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f
   };
   printf("GLfloat variable called successfully\n"); 
   GLuint ShaderProgram = glCreateProgram();
   GLuint ShaderObjv = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
   GLuint ShaderObjf = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
   const GLchar* pvs[1];
   const GLchar* pfs[1];
   const char* pVertexShaderText = "#version 330\nlayout(location = 0) in vec3 Position;\nlayout(location = 1) in vec3 incolor;\nlayout(location = 2) in vec2 Tex;\nout vec3 outcolor;\nout vec2 texcoords;\nvoid main(){gl_Position = vec4(Position.x, Position.y, Position.z, 1.0);\noutcolor = incolor;\ntexcoords = Tex;}";
   const char* pFragmentShaderText = "#version 330\nuniform vec3 color;\nuniform sampler2D tex0;\nin vec3 outcolor;\nin vec2 texcoords;\nout vec4 FragColor;\nvoid main(){FragColor = texture(tex0, texcoords);}";
   pvs[0] = pVertexShaderText;
   pfs[0] = pFragmentShaderText;
   GLint LenghtsVertex[1];
   GLint LenghtsFragment[1];
   LenghtsVertex[0] = strlen(pVertexShaderText);
   LenghtsFragment[0] = strlen(pFragmentShaderText);
   glShaderSource(ShaderObjv, 1, pvs, LenghtsVertex);
   glShaderSource(ShaderObjf, 1, pfs, LenghtsFragment);
   glCompileShader(ShaderObjv);
   glCompileShader(ShaderObjf);
   GLint successvs;
   glGetShaderiv(ShaderObjv, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &successvs);
   if (!successvs) {
       GLchar InfoLog1[1024];
       glGetShaderInfoLog(ShaderObjv, sizeof(InfoLog1), NULL, InfoLog1);
       fprintf(stderr, "Error compiling shader type %d: '%s'\n", GL_VERTEX_SHADER, InfoLog1);
   }
   GLint successfs;
   glGetShaderiv(ShaderObjf, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &successfs);
   if (!successfs) {
       GLchar InfoLog2[1024];
       glGetShaderInfoLog(ShaderObjf, sizeof(InfoLog2), NULL, InfoLog2);
       fprintf(stderr, "Error compiling shader type %d: '%s'\n", GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, InfoLog2);
   }
   glAttachShader(ShaderProgram, ShaderObjv);
   glAttachShader(ShaderProgram, ShaderObjf);
   glLinkProgram(ShaderProgram);
   glValidateProgram(ShaderProgram);
   glUseProgram(ShaderProgram);
   GLint uniColor = glGetUniformLocation(ShaderProgram, "color");
   GLint tex0uni = glGetUniformLocation(ShaderProgram, "tex0");
   glUniform3f(uniColor, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
   glUniform1i(tex0uni, 0);
   glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
   GLuint VBO;
   GLuint VAO = 0;
   GLuint EBO;
   glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);
   glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
   glGenBuffers(1, &EBO);
   glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
   glBindVertexArray(VAO);
   glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, EBO);
   printf("Buffer created successfully\n");
   glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(Vertices), Vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
   glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(indices), indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
   printf("Buffer data set up successfully\n");
   glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
   glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
   glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);
   printf("Enabling buffer successfull\n");
   glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
   printf("Binding buffer successfull\n");
   int width, height, num;
   unsigned char* bytes = stbi_load("image.png", &width, &height, &num, 0);
   GLuint texture;
   glGenTextures(1, &texture);
   glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
   glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
   glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
   glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
   glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_BORDER);
   glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_BORDER);
   float flatcolor[] = {1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f};
   glTexParameterfv(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_BORDER_COLOR, flatcolor);
   printf("Set parameters successfully\n");
   glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, width, height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, bytes);
   glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
   printf("Texture set successfully\n");
   glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 8 * sizeof(float), (void*)0);
   printf("First pointer succeeded\n");
   glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 8 * sizeof(float), (void*)(3 * sizeof(float)));
   printf("Second pointer succeeded\n");
   glVertexAttribPointer(2, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 8 * sizeof(float), (void*)(6 * sizeof(float)));
   printf("Third pointer succeeded\n");
   printf("Setting up VectexAttribPointer successfull\n");

   while(!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)){
      glfwPollEvents();  
      glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
      glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f); 
      //glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3); 
      glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0); 
      GLenum err;
      if((err = glGetError()) != GL_NO_ERROR){
         printf("OpenGL error: %d\n", err);
      }
      glfwSwapBuffers(window);
   } 
   return 0;
}


void key_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mods)
{
   if(key == GLFW_KEY_R && action == GLFW_PRESS){
      glUniform3f(uniColor, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
   }else if(key == GLFW_KEY_G && action == GLFW_PRESS){
      glUniform3f(uniColor, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
   }else if(key == GLFW_KEY_B && action == GLFW_PRESS){
      glUniform3f(uniColor, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
   }
}
```

Comment: Your problem obviously come from texture coordinates, I don't found where you define the vertices texture coordinates in your code sample.

Comment: @Sedenion The cordinates are the last 2 entries in every line of the Vertices array.

Comment: Ok, sorry, I see. I think it is just a mater of vertices order, try to modify these coordinates to understand how this modify your final result, then understands what happen. You'd probably better use a specific UV-test texture that allow you to properly identify which part of the texture is rendered where: https://i.stack.imgur.com/q11Gd.png

Comment: Your texture coordinates aren't the same shape as your vertex positions

Comment: @Sedenion, I think, that the problem isn't in the texture cordinates, because the two triangles do not split the texture and just duplicate it. Also I had my coordinates messed up, but I fixed them. The window now shows two textures of the image for both the triangles. How do I combine them?

Comment: @RadoslavL Can you, please, provide the original image, or/and use a proper UV chart testing image, so we can understand how the original image is mapped on your triangles ? Your problem come from the texture coordinates, at one level or another.

Comment: @Sedenion This is the original image: http://0x0.st/oaPK.png

Comment: @RadoslavL ok, something weird happen, from one triangle to another, some UV coordinates are messed up. Can you provide your vertex and fragment shaders ? Also, try to set all your normals values to 1.0f, then all to 0.0f, to checks whether you see something change, in case you have some wrong pointer alignment (it seem not, but...)

Comment: This is the vertex shader code - https://campfirebg.eu5.org/upload/linux/OpenGL/vs.txt and this is the fragment shader code - https://campfirebg.eu5.org/upload/linux/OpenGL/fs.txt

Comment: Everything seems ok. At this point I have no clue. Try changing values here and there (try other values than 0.0f and 1.0f) to spot changes and understand what happen, use an UV chart texture to have a better view on how coordinates are changed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved! I had to add `glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);`, because of the odd resolution of the image. As far as I know it limits the bytes sent at the same time to only 1.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem has nothing to do with the shader.
The cause are wrong texture coordinates here:

```
float Vertices[] = {
    -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
     0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
    -0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
     0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f
};
```

The x and y coordinates and the texture coordinates only match up in the first line.

This is the corrected version:

```
float Vertices[] = {
    -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
     0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
    -0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
     0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f
};
```

Comment: The main issue still remains, but thanks! The main problem is, that it splits the texture between the triangles, that make up the square. I want to make a texture, that is spread along both of the triangles.

Comment: I added your changes and it still isn't working. Look at the changed code and picture.

Comment: Try changing the order of the texture coordinates until it displays correctly

Comment: The texture is split between triangles and I set all the coordinates properly.